# unable to save a token after successful login

Tags: javascript, api

I want to save a token after succesful login,but I cant really figure it out. I am still new in javascript.

below is what the login api returns:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "message": "Login successful",
    "data": [
        {
            "merchant_code": "000004",
            "token": "4d9519909d99b3d451abeff1512b540e3319124f"
        }
    ]
}
```

this is what I did for integrating the api using javascript:

```
 fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login", {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(payload)
        }).then((res) => res.json()).then((response) => {
          if (response.message === "Login successful") {
            console.log('login successful');
          }
          else {
            Swal.fire({
              icon: 'error',
              title: 'Error',
              text: 'Login was unsuccessful, please try again',
              confirmButtonColor: 'red',  
            }) 
          }

          console.log(response);
        }).catch((e) => {
          Swal.fire({
            icon: 'error',
            title: 'Error',
            text: 'Server down, Please try again later!',
            confirmButtonColor: 'red',  
          }) 
        });
```

now all I need help is how to safe the token and how to use it again on the apis that will require the token, like getting the data of current logged user.

Comment: What specific issue are you having? Where were you going to store the token, e.g., local storage, cookie, ...?

Comment: Why are checking the `message` property to determine success, when there is a `success` property right there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage).

So...

```
fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login", {
    ...
}).then((res) => res.json()).then((response) => {

    if (response.message === "Login successful") {

        sessionStorage.setItem("token", response.data[0].token);
        sessionStorage.setItem("merchant_code", response.data[0].merchant_code);

    }

}).catch((e) => {
    ...
});
```

And when you need to access a protected endpoint:

```
if (sessionStorage.getItem("token")) {
    
    // user is logged in

} else {

   // user is not

}
```

And to log the user out, destroying session information, use [sessionStorage.clear()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/clear) or [sessionStorage.removeItem()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/removeItem)

Comment: It is working quite well thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You may store Token in localStorage, Cookies etc. But it's not that much Safe. However, You can consider ***in-memory*** in Browser.
Here's a reference [URL](https://mannharleen.github.io/2020-03-19-handling-jwt-securely-part-1/).

Comment: Really appreaciate your efforts it is working quite well

Answer (score 0):

save it as  localStorage

```
 fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(payload)
    }).then((res) => res.json()).then((response) => {
      if (response.message === "Login successful") {
        console.log('login successful');
      // look herer
       localStorage.setItem('user',response.data);  
      }
      else {
        Swal.fire({
          icon: 'error',
          title: 'Error',
          text: 'Login was unsuccessful, please try again',
          confirmButtonColor: 'red',  
        }) 
      }

      console.log(response);
    }).catch((e) => {
      Swal.fire({
        icon: 'error',
        title: 'Error',
        text: 'Server down, Please try again later!',
        confirmButtonColor: 'red',  
      }) 
    });
```

Comment: to find out is user logged or not  needs check   this way   localStorage.getItem('user')

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation is working quite well